# Calling C++ function using DllImport

Tags: c#, .net, c++, unmanaged, dllimport

This one is basic, how do I call the function SubscribeNewsFeed in the following from a C# DllImport?

```
class LogAppender : public L_Append
{
public:
    LogAppender()
        : outfile("TestLog.txt", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out)
        , feedSubscribed(false)
    {
        outfile.setf(0, std::ios::floatfield);
        outfile.precision(4);
    }



    void SubscribeNewsFeed()
    {
        someOtherCalls();
    }

};
```

I'm unable to figure out how to include the class name when using the DllImport in my C# program here:

```
 class Program
    {

        [DllImport("LogAppender.dll")]
        public static extern void SubscribeNewsFeed();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubscribeNewsFeed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even in C++ you'd need to instantiate a LogAppender to call that on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PInvoke cannot be used to call directly into a C++ function in this way.  Instead you need to define an `extern "C"` function which calls the PInvoke function and PInvoke into that function.  Additionally you cannot PInvoke into a class instance method.

C / C++ Code

```
extern "C" void SubscribeNewsFeedHelper() {
  LogAppender appender;
  appender.SubscribeNewsFeed();
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("LogAppender.dll")]
public static extern void SubscribeNewsFeedHelper();
```

Answer (score 1):

P/Invoke doesn't work that way. It only can import C functions. So there are different types of interop between the managed (C#) and native (C++) world. Interop via COM would be a solution - providing a C interface another.