# Import c++ DLL to c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Please help me with DLLImpot in c#.
I have DLL, analysed it with DLL Export Viewer, this class method is shown:

```
public: static float * __cdecl Evaluator::calculateLM(float *,float *,int,int,float *,float *)
```

I just can't figure out how to `DllImport` it into c#.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7955767/555547

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

```
[DllImport("LMModelSolve.dll",
            EntryPoint = "?calculateLM@Evaluator@@SAPAMPAM0HH00@Z",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)
        ]
        static extern IntPtr calculateLM(float[] x, float[] y, int n, int iterations, float[] lower, float[] upper);
```

And to call and get result:

```
IntPtr res = calculateLM(x, y, ndata, 200, lower, upper);
            float[] resultVertices = new float[4];
            Marshal.Copy(res,resultVertices,0,4);
```

Comment: This is normally a memory leak since you cannot release the returned array.  You'd better test that, call it a million times.